# Save recorded audio file to database in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

i'm new at JavaScript, i want to create a .Net web application that records audio files (wma) from microphone and save it into an SQL Server database, to be played later,

Here is the example i'm using : [GitHub](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

In that example the audio file is recorded by i don't know where is the *.wma file so i can stream it and save it into my database.

Where can i find the physical audio file ?

```
<script>
        function __log(e, data) {
            log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
        }

        var audio_context;
        var recorder;

        function startUserMedia(stream) {
            var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            __log('Media stream created.');

            // Uncomment if you want the audio to feedback directly
            //input.connect(audio_context.destination);
            //__log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

            recorder = new Recorder(input);
            __log('Recorder initialised.');
        }

        function startRecording(button) {
            recorder && recorder.record();
            button.disabled = true;
            button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
            __log('Recording...');
        }

        function stopRecording(button) {
            recorder && recorder.stop();
            button.disabled = true;
            button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
            __log('Stopped recording.');

            // create WAV download link using audio data blob
            createDownloadLink();

            recorder.clear();
        }

        function createDownloadLink() {
            recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                var au = document.createElement('audio');
                var hf = document.createElement('a');

                au.controls = true;
                au.src = url;
                alert(url);
                hf.href = url;
                hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
                hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
                li.appendChild(au);
                li.appendChild(hf);
                recordingslist.appendChild(li);
            });
        }

        window.onload = function init() {
            try {
                // webkit shim
                window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                audio_context = new AudioContext;
                __log('Audio context set up.');
                __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
            } catch (e) {
                alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
            }

            navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, startUserMedia, function (e) {
                __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
            });
        };
  </script>
```

Comment: that wma part is a tall order, might want/have to do that server-side and ship a wav to the server. to get the wav, use its `this.exportWAV` method

Comment: euh, sorry i didn't understand what you mean...